# Is the Sattva-Rajas-Tamas classification considered important in Advaita?

Tags: advaita, gunas

Since the Advaitic Brahman has no qualities - it must be that all these Gunas are obstructions to achieving Samadhi.

Are there Advaitic statements that one must transcend all three Gunas?

Comment: Krishna Himself says in the Gita that we should transcends all three gunas so Advaita, like all Vedantic philosophies accepts it.

Comment: BTW, there are three Advaita schools of India - 1. Kashmiri Shaivism, 2. Advaita Vedanta, 3. Mahayana Buddhism... You can check all these especially Kashmiri Shaivism which gives heavy doses of mysticism, philosophy and occultism...

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. Although your comment is correct about Mahayana Buddhism, it doesn't belong to Hinduism.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I used the word Indian. It's indigenous.

Comment: @SK My following answer also answers this Q: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32680/4732

Answer (score 2):

For now presenting non-subtle answer only...

Although the door to samaadhi is from sattva as a psychological quality, one has to eventually transcend it according to advaita. From Bhagwat Geeta

> BG 2.45: The Vedas deal with **the three modes of material nature, O Arjun. Rise above the three modes to a state of pure spiritual consciousness.** Freeing yourself from dualities, eternally fixed in truth, and without concern for material gain and safety, be situated in the self.

Here, I think pure spiritual consciousness is nothing but a state of no mind - beyond chitta or samadhi.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the Sattva-Rajas-Tamas classification considered important in Advaita?

It is important in Advaita, as well as all Vedantic Sampradayas.

> Are there Advaitic statements that one must transcend all three Gunas?

They are not merely *Advaitic* statements, but Vedic statements, since the Bhagavad Gita says the same thing:

> **14.23** - He is said to transcended the Gunas, who remains like one indifferent, undisturbed by the Gunas; and who, knowing that it is the
>   Gunas that are active, remains stable and does not act;

Ramanujacharya's commentary for verses 22 and 23:

> One [who is liberated from the Gunas] does not resent the effects of
>   Sattva, Rajas and Tamas known as enlightenment, industry and delusion,
>   respectively, when they arise in regard to things different from the
>   Self which are undesirable; nor does one crave the things that are
>   different from the Self, but desirable, when they are withdrawn.
>
> He who remains like one indifferent — namely, who is joyful in the
>   realisation of the ātman as being different from the Gunas and is
>   unconcerned about material things and is not therefore disturbed
>   through aversion and attraction and who remains quiescent, reflecting
>   that the Gunas produce their own effects like illumination etc., and
>   so remains inactive and does fall under the control of the Gunas.