# Primary weapon of kalki

Tags: avatars, weapon, kalki

Many of the avatars of Vishnu that has happened, who were supposed to kill someone or destroy something has some kind of primary weapons.

Though they all can use various kinds of weapons, but had one primary weapon as their symbolic one, for instance:

1. Narasimha avatar had his nails
2. Parshurama had an axe
3. Rama had a bow and arrow
4. Krishna had Sudarshan Charkra

Similarly,
**Are there any descriptions telling us about the primary weapon that will be used by Kalki?**

Comment: His primary weapon will be a sword, sometimes described as a flaming sword.

Comment: He will use a futuristic advanced sword. Btw Narsingh did not have a weapon.

Comment: Keypad and a pen is mightier than a sword don’t you think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How will the Kalki avatar look like?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/how-will-the-kalki-avatar-look-like)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa): Skandha 12: Adhyay 2](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/2/19-20/), the primary weapon of Lord Kalki would be a **sword** (**असि**) and his vahana wold be a horse named Devadatta:

> अश्वमाशुगमारुह्य देवदत्तं जगत्पति: ।
>
> असिनासाधुदमनमष्टैश्वर्यगुणान्वित: ॥ १९ ॥
>
> Lord Kalki, the Lord of the universe, will mount His swift horse Devadatta and, **sword** in hand, travel over the earth exhibiting His eight mystic opulences and eight special qualities of Godhead.

Comment: Just give a space after the star to make that Sanskrit word bold :-)

Comment: @KrishnaShweta technically we can't give space there..else some vibhakti or sandhi would break and the meaning would be completely different..i removed * instead..

Comment: I understand, now it looks better

Answer (score 6):

As written in [wiki article on Kalki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalki) under his bio; His primary weapon will be Ranta Maru which is weapon of Shiva and is a sword.

Also same [**wiki article's description**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalki#Description) says:

> Kalki is an avatara of Vishnu. Avatara means "descent" and refers to a descent of the divine into the material realm of human existence. The Garuda Purana lists ten avatars, with Kalki being the tenth. He is described as the avatar who appears at the end of the Kali Yuga. He ends the darkest, degenerating and chaotic stage of the Kali Yuga (period) to remove adharma and **ushers in the Satya Yuga, while riding a white horse with a fiery sword.** He restarts a new cycle of time. He is described as a Brahmin warrior in the Puranas.

Also in Kalki Purana, it is mentioned that after his Guru suggestion Lord Kalki starts worshiping Lord Shiva and Lord Shiva blesses him  3 things horse, a parrot and a sword.

> Text 25
>
> This horse was manifested from Garuda, and it can go anywhere at
>   will and assume many different forms. Here also is a parrot that knows
>   everything—past, present, and future. **I would like to offer You both the
>   horse and the parrot and so please accept them**
>
> Text 26
>
> By the influence of this horse and parrot, the people of the world will
>   know You as a learned scholar of all scriptures who is a master of the art
>   of releasing arrows, and thus the conqueror of all.
>
> Text 27
>
> **I would also like to present You this sharp, strong sword and so please
>   accept it.** The handle of this sword is bedecked with jewels, and it is
>   extremely powerful. As such, this sword will help You to reduce the heavy
>   burden of the earth.

Reference Link : [Kalki Purana](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByTCDrDij9HBWVA4VHYzY2g4elU/edit?pref=2&pli=1)

Comment: this fiery sword and a white horse, really makes me wonder if they would actually be an actual horse and a sword or something really really futuristic :)

Comment: @V.Aggarwal Only beautiful souls would witness his appearance. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Srimad Bhagavatam](http://bhagavata.org/canto12/chapter2.html), a sword is his weapon and a white horse is his ride.

> (17) The spiritual master of all the moving and nonmoving living
>   beings, Lord Vishnu, the Supreme Personality and Controller of All,
>   takes birth for the protection of the religion and to put an end to
>   the karma of the saintly souls. (18) In the village of S'ambhala Lord
>   Kalki will appear in the home of the great soul, the eminent brahmin
>   Vishnuyas'â ['the glory of Vishnu']. (19-20) **Mounting His swift
>   horse Devadatta, the Lord of the Universe endowed with His sword**,
>   transcendental qualities and eight mystic opulences [siddhis], will
>   subdue the reprobates. With speed traveling the earth on His horse He,
>   unrivaled in His splendor, will slaughter the thieves dressing as
>   kings by the millions. (21) When all the robbers have been killed, the
>   minds of all the residents of the towns and cities will clear up who
>   came in touch with the breeze carrying the most sacred fragrance of
>   the [with sandalwood paste] decorated body of Lord Vâsudeva

Comment: You have found a nice similarity, though there is no telling if here bible is talking about the same person as we are. there could only be speculations. :) but a really nice catch.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal Abrahmic religions are an extension of Sanatan Dharma for mlecchas  https://truth-is-victorious.blogspot.com/2019/01/lord-kalki-is-jesus-is-isa-ibn-mariyam.html . Satvik Hindus(+Buddhists), Rajsik Christains and Tamsik Muslims form 78% of world population, 2% other religions and rest are atheists, explained here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35195/16530

Comment: This is a Q&A site for Hinduism . All the answers should be written from Hinduism perspective only. You have quoted Bible in your answer. Its interpretation may vary and is debatable. Please limit your answer to Hinduism only.