# Eating vegetarian beef as a Hindu

Tags: dharma-shastras, food

Eating meat is prohibited in Manu Smriti.

The people who eat vegetarian beef have the same impure thought as the people who eat real beef.

Should vegetarian beef be prohibited for Hindus?

Comment: vegetarian beef ?

Comment: What is vegetarian beef?

Comment: A company named Beyond Meat is making vegetarian burgers which it claims tastes exactly like beef.

Comment: @DANBHATT if an answer satisfies you, that answer is apt to what is asked in question by you, you can click tick mark and accept the answer.

Comment: IIf Asker could explain what is the material/ what is contained in the material could be helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Before seeking this answer you should understand why non-veg food is prohibited in Hinduism, Or I should say, not preferred instead of being prohibited.

All the tasks that one does in his life, thoughts he had, the food he eats are broadly divided into 3 categories called "Gunas" (or traits/characteristics).

Refer to these post [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35186/what-are-sattva-rajas-and-tamas) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/112/15734) to understand these **3 Gunas**.

Non-veg food (not just beef, all kinds of it) is considered to be of type **"Tamas"**, and in Hinduism, all people are supposed to be moving towards sattva guna, hence non-veg food is not preferred.

On the other hand, the food that is deep-fried, too many spices (basically fast food) is tamas or rajas in itself, therefore most spiritual seekers do not prefer fast food at all.

However for normal people, if it is only limited to the taste of it and contents are vegetarian, then it totally depends on the individual's perception of it. Some may seek this as an opportunity to have a taste of beef while others (me included) may not be wanting to taste it at all, even knowing that technically it's vegetarian only.

```
Should vegetarian beef be prohibited for Hindus?
```

Fundamentally, Hinduism does not prohibit anything for anyone, it just tells the effects and consequences of doing and not doing certain things (Karma), other than that, each individual is free to follow his own free will.

I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Also, I have to add beyond meat is a company that is used by vegans in USA. These people have left non vegetarian food along with milk products and animal products of all kinds because they think it is cruel to animals. Hence their actions are obviously NOT tamasic.